# matplotlib: Convert Hour string to float

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to plot the following csv data as the x-axis with matplotlib:

```
Time
00:00:00
01:00:00
02:00:00
03:00:00
04:00:00
05:00:00
06:00:00
07:00:00
08:00:00
09:00:00
10:00:00
11:00:00
12:00:00
13:00:00
14:00:00
15:00:00
16:00:00
17:00:00
18:00:00
19:00:00
20:00:00
21:00:00
22:00:00
23:00:00
```

But I keep getting the error:

```
ValueError: could not convert string to float: '23:00:00'
```

How Can I convert these values to Hour format in matplotlib?

Here is my code:

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(15,7))
ax = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1) # row-col-num
# --- line plot data on the Axes
ax.plot(df3['YYYY-MO-DD HH-MI-SS_SSS'], df3['ATMOSPHERIC PRESSURE (hPa) mean'], 'b-', linewidth=2,
label=r'office Phone1')
```

Any ideas?

Thank you !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message

```
ValueError: could not convert string to float: '23:00:00'
```

implies that one of the inputs -- probably `df3['YYYY-MO-DD HH-MI-SS_SSS']` -- contains strings when `ax.plot` was expecting floats.

`ax.plot`, however, can accept datetime-like objects instead of floats as well. So it would suffice to convert `df3['YYYY-MO-DD HH-MI-SS_SSS']` to datetime-like objects.

Using pandas, you can do that using the `parse_dates` parameter of `pd.read_csv` (assuming `df3` is defined with `pd.read_csv`), or you can convert that column to datetime-like objects after-the-fact:

```
date_col = 'YYYY-MO-DD HH-MI-SS_SSS'
df3[date_col] = pd.to_datetime(df3[date_col])
```

---

For example,

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

np.random.seed(2016)
date_col = 'YYYY-MO-DD HH-MI-SS_SSS'

df = pd.DataFrame( {date_col: [
    '00:00:00', '01:00:00', '02:00:00', '03:00:00', '04:00:00', '05:00:00',
    '06:00:00', '07:00:00', '08:00:00', '09:00:00', '10:00:00', '11:00:00',
    '12:00:00', '13:00:00', '14:00:00', '15:00:00', '16:00:00', '17:00:00',
    '18:00:00', '19:00:00', '20:00:00', '21:00:00', '22:00:00', '23:00:00'],
                'foo': np.random.random(24)})
df[date_col] = pd.to_datetime(df[date_col])

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(df[date_col], df['foo'], 'b-', linewidth=2, label='foo')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: I am not sure whether it is really necessary to go to this complexity. Pandas is a nice library, but you can convert these strings to a datetime object without pandas as well.

Comment: @Chiel: Perhaps it was presumptuous of me, but when I saw the variable was named `df3` I assumed it was a Pandas DataFrame. If that is correct, then there is no reason not to take advantage of the convenience Pandas offers.

Comment: @unutbu In that case, you have provided the most appropriate solution.